# Print a PDF of the screen

Tags: pdf-generation, jasperserver

My question is -

In `Jasper Reports`, is it possible to print a PDF of the screen that is been shown?

I have created a **dashboard**, that shows some data in a tabular format. Now, on clicking a button, the **dashboard should be downloaded as a PDF file**. Is this feature possible in `Jasper Reports`?

Comment: `is it possible to print a PDF of the screen that is been shown?` - The screen of what?

Comment: @AlexK the screen will be showing a dashboard. I want to print the dashboard as a PDF